# php array() w/ foreach only loops if using .= to build the result

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a very frustrating problem which I cannot result. Its just not adding up.

I am passing an array to process on a **foreach()** like so:

```
if (is_array($seminar)) {
foreach ($seminar as $sem_id)
    $sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";
    echo "$sem_id<br />";
}
```

As you can see my array() is $seminar, and that output looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 13
    [4] => 14
    [5] => 15
)
```

As you can see in my code, I am building a block w/ **=.** like: *$sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";* and the when echoed out looks like: 389131415 as expected.

BUT when I simply trying to iterate through and print each value like: *echo "$sem_id
";* I only get the last array() item!!

I've never run into this problem before. I am guessing I am missing something dead simple here, but from all my experience this should be working and printing those results just fine.

As a side note, var_dump($seminar); produces this too:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "8" [2]=> string(1) "9" [3]=> string(2) "13" [4]=> string(2) "14" [5]=> string(2) "15" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the opening brace of the `foreach` and a closing brace. Try:

```
if (is_array($seminar)) {
  foreach ($seminar as $sem_id) {
    $sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";
    echo "$sem_id<br />";
  }
}
```

or build the list and print it at the end:

```
if (is_array($seminar)) {
  foreach ($seminar as $sem_id) {
    $sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";
  }
  echo "$sem_id_list";
}
```

Comment: And if the OP had indented his code properly, this would have been quite obvious.

Comment: Yup that was it. I can't believe I missed that! I guess a new set of eyes can see a lot more.

Comment: Note that OP's code is still technically valid, it's just not what he wants to do. The new line + indentation is a way to avoid brackets or colons, but only the next line will execute in the block, which is why the second one only prints the last item, as `$sem_id` becomes a global variable, defined only by the last iteration. The other answer makes an attempt at explaining this.

Comment: Indentation, and the habit of writing open/closing braces before block bodies, can help you avoid this in the future.

Comment: Yes I of course will Accept this Answer. I just have to wait ten mins before I can do so by the modules of StackOverflow. And I will second Wesley Murch.. I've written my foreach() loops like this before that's what was so confounding, but I see w/out the brackets it redefines the way it works.

Comment: @Shelhamer: As long as we're talking best practices, you don't need quotes around `"$sem_id"` or `echo "$sem_id_list";`

Answer (score 2):

you are missing {} for your loop check

```
  if (is_array($seminar)) {
foreach ($seminar as $sem_id){
    $sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";
    echo "$sem_id<br />";
}
}
```

http://codepad.org/0UZpQOZx

If you don't give {} there will be only one statement in your loop which is

```
   $sem_id_list .= "$sem_id";
```

and line         `echo "$sem_id<br />";` will only executed once after completion of loop.